# Transfor a Gif to a grob in R to use with annotation_custom in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gif, grob

I am trying to import a gif and turn it into a grob to use it with the function annotation_custom in a ggplot, so far I imported it and have been able to turn it into an image.

So far this is what I have:

```
library(caTools)
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)
require(gridExtra)
y <- read.gif("http://blog.helpingadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/basketballcourt.gif")
```

and I get a list, so far I have been able to plot it:

```
image(y$image, col=y$col, main=y$comment, asp=1)
```

But I have tried to transform it to a grob:

```
a <- rasterGrob(image(y$image, col=y$col, main=y$comment, asp=1))
```

or try

```
raster(image(y$image, col=y$col, main=y$comment, asp=1))
```

and then save it as a grob, but since image returns class NULL it does not work.

I've also tried to use the matrix from y, but it gets really strange colours:

```
plot(raster(y$image))
```

and I really need the original colours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mat = y$col[y$image+1]
dim(mat) = dim(y$image)
qplot(1,1) + annotation_custom(rasterGrob(mat))
```

[image]